# How to disable MenuItems based on a DataGrid DependencyProperty in a WPF ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to achieve the following:

The projects is based on a Prism MVVM environment. In my main ResourceDictionary I have a generic ContextMenu that works for all my custom MyDataGrid. 
This context menu has a binding to the ViewModel of the current MyDataGrid where some commands are declared. This part is already in place and works as expected.

Now I need also to disable some ContextMenu functions based on some custom MyDataGrid dependency properties.

The problem I face is that I can just reach the single DataGridRow that has been clicked by using PlacementTarget, but not the parent MyDataGrid where the dependency property is declared.

This is the ContextMenu and it's binding to a DataGridRow:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyPrismModule.Wpf">

<ContextMenu x:Key="MyCommonContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="MyFunction"
              Command="{Binding
                    Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.Template.MyFunction,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding
                    Path=PlacementTarget,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
        <MenuItem.Style>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.Parent.MyDependencyProperty }" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Style>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyDataGrid}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCommonContextMenu}}"/>
</Style>
```

To reach the MyDataGrid.MyDependencyProperty I tried this PlacementTarget.Parent.MyDependencyProperty but it's not working.

The idea of using Parent was originally taken from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b01ba4e-d6a8-4e95-b8a0-bd3633bca2bd/binding-to-another-element-inside-a-template?forum=wpf

Thanks to everyone who will take time to look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have already done all work. Small improvement is to **set not the `DataContext` but  `MyDataGrid` to the `DataGridRow.Tag`** and access it later via `PlacementTarget.Tag`.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyCommonContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.MyDependencyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.YourViemodelProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
</ContextMenu>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyDataGrid}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCommonContextMenu}}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rekshino for enlightening me! I was close but I could not see this obvious solution :)